# rails 3.1, why certificate verify failed when using Heroku logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am having a problem reading the logs of my Heroku app, please see the problem below:

```
$heroku logs

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client.rb:409:in `read_logs'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/logs.rb:31:in `index'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:135:in `run'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
from /usr/bin/heroku:30:in `<main>'
```

here is my gem environment:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :benchmark => false
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   http://rubygems.org/
----------------------
IDE: JetBrains RubyMine 4.0.1, build #RM-113.20
OS: Linux 3.0.0-16-generic[i386]
Java: 1.6.0_23-b23
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p0 [global]
Sdk Version: ver.1.9.3p0 ( revision 33570) p0
Ruby Interpreter: /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: yes, gemset:global
RVM Home: /home/sam/.rvm
Sdk Language Level: 1.9
Sdk Load Path:
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     /opt/RubyMine-4.0.1/rubystubs19
Sdk Gem paths: 
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bundler/gems
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems
Gems used for 'hope':
     xpath (bundled(0.1.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/xpath-0.1.4
     rack (1.3.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-1.3.6
     rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-expectations-2.7.0
     rack-mount (bundled(0.8.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3
     bcrypt-ruby (bundled(3.0.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
     activemodel (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0
     client_side_validations (3.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.4
     cocoon (bundled(1.0.15))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/cocoon-1.0.15
     diff-lcs (1.1.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3
     sprockets (2.0.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/sprockets-2.0.3
     rack-ssl (1.3.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2
     simple_form (1.5.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/simple_form-1.5.2
     thor (bundled(0.14.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6
     rdoc (3.12)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rdoc-3.12
     rubyzip (bundled(0.9.6.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip-0.9.6.1
     foreigner (1.1.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/foreigner-1.1.1
     thin (bundled(1.3.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1
     mocha (bundled(0.10.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mocha-0.10.3
     mime-types (bundled(1.17.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mime-types-1.17.2
     therubyracer (bundled(0.9.9))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.9.9
     treetop (bundled(1.4.10))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.10
     kaminari (bundled(0.13.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.13.0
     coffee-script (2.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0
     sass (bundled(3.1.14))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.14
     mail (bundled(2.3.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0
     will_paginate (bundled(3.0.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/will_paginate-3.0.3
     rack-mount (0.8.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3
     rspec-mocks (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-mocks-2.7.0
     i18n (0.6.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/i18n-0.6.0
     orm_adapter (0.0.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/orm_adapter-0.0.6
     rspec-core (2.7.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1
     daemons (bundled(1.1.8))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.8
     pg (0.13.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/pg-0.13.2
     metaclass (0.0.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/metaclass-0.0.1
     builder (3.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/builder-3.0.0
     execjs (bundled(1.3.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0
     uglifier (bundled(1.2.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.2.3
     jquery-rails (bundled(1.0.19))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19
     rspec-expectations (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-2.7.0
     eventmachine (bundled(0.12.10))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10
     bundler (1.0.21)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21
     rspec-rails (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0
     warden (1.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/warden-1.1.0
     rails (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rails-3.1.0
     sass-rails (3.1.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/sass-rails-3.1.5
     rspec (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-2.7.0
     actionpack (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/actionpack-3.1.0
     rack (bundled(1.3.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6
     mime-types (1.17.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/mime-types-1.17.2
     nokogiri (bundled(1.5.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0
     capybara (bundled(1.1.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.2
     rake (0.9.2.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2
     nokogiri (1.5.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0
     sqlite3 (1.3.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5
     actionmailer (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0
     therubyracer (0.9.9)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/therubyracer-0.9.9
     metaclass (bundled(0.0.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/metaclass-0.0.1
     launchy (2.0.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/launchy-2.0.5
     rack-cache (bundled(1.0.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3
     rdoc (bundled(3.12))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-3.12
     polyglot (0.3.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/polyglot-0.3.3
     tilt (bundled(1.3.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3
     uglifier (1.2.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/uglifier-1.2.3
     treetop (1.4.10)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/treetop-1.4.10
     warden (bundled(1.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.0
     coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/coffee-script-source-1.2.0
     ffi (1.0.11)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/ffi-1.0.11
     rb-fsevent (bundled(0.9.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.0
     ffi (bundled(1.0.11))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11
     arel (bundled(2.2.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.2.1
     kaminari (0.13.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/kaminari-0.13.0
     guard (bundled(1.0.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.0.0
     coffee-rails (3.1.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1
     validate_url (bundled(0.2.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/validate_url-0.2.0
     actionmailer (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0
     turn (bundled(0.9.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.9.2
     rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-mocks-2.7.0
     coffee-rails (bundled(3.1.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1
     capybara-webkit (bundled(0.9.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.9.0
     childprocess (bundled(0.3.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.1
     execjs (1.3.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/execjs-1.3.0
     sprockets (bundled(2.0.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3
     tilt (1.3.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/tilt-1.3.3
     rspec (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-2.7.0
     rspec-rails (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0
     tzinfo (0.3.31)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/tzinfo-0.3.31
     haml (bundled(3.1.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.1.4
     rake (bundled(0.9.2.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2
     bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
     pg (bundled(0.13.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.13.2
     actionpack (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0
     devise (bundled(1.5.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.2
     database_cleaner (0.7.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/database_cleaner-0.7.1
     foreigner (bundled(1.1.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/foreigner-1.1.1
     addressable (bundled(2.2.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.6
     selenium-webdriver (bundled(2.19.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0
     rspec-core (bundled(2.7.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1
     simple_form (bundled(1.5.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/simple_form-1.5.2
     builder (bundled(3.0.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/builder-3.0.0
     erubis (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.7.0
     orm_adapter (bundled(0.0.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/orm_adapter-0.0.6
     validate_url (0.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/validate_url-0.2.0
     cocoon (1.0.15)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/cocoon-1.0.15
     addressable (2.2.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/addressable-2.2.6
     haml (3.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/haml-3.1.4
     hike (1.2.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/hike-1.2.1
     libv8 (bundled(3.3.10.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux
     coffee-script-source (bundled(1.2.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-source-1.2.0
     erubis (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/erubis-2.7.0
     spork (bundled(1.0.0rc2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc2
     capybara (1.1.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/capybara-1.1.2
     tzinfo (bundled(0.3.31))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-0.3.31
     jquery-rails (1.0.19)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19
     json (1.6.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/json-1.6.5
     factory_girl (bundled(2.5.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.5.1
     factory_girl_rails (bundled(1.6.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.6.0
     hike (bundled(1.2.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.1
     rack-cache (1.0.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3
     activeresource (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activeresource-3.1.0
     railties (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0
     libv8 (3.3.10.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux
     rack-test (bundled(0.6.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.1
     i18n (bundled(0.6.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.0
     sass-rails (bundled(3.1.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.1.5
     multi_json (1.0.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/multi_json-1.0.4
     sqlite3 (bundled(1.3.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5
     xpath (0.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/xpath-0.1.4
     coffee-script (bundled(2.2.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0
     activemodel (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activemodel-3.1.0
     activesupport (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activesupport-3.1.0
     devise (1.5.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/devise-1.5.2
     ansi (bundled(1.4.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ansi-1.4.2
     polyglot (bundled(0.3.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3
     json (bundled(1.6.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.5
     mail (2.3.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/mail-2.3.0
     client_side_validations (bundled(3.1.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.4
     activerecord (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activerecord-3.1.0
     rack-ssl (bundled(1.3.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2
     guard-spork (bundled(0.5.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/guard-spork-0.5.2
     rack-test (0.6.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-test-0.6.1
     activerecord (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0
     arel (2.2.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/arel-2.2.1
     activesupport (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0
     rails (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.1.0
     activeresource (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.1.0
     launchy (bundled(2.0.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/launchy-2.0.5
     railties (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/railties-3.1.0
     ansi (1.4.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/ansi-1.4.2
     multi_json (bundled(1.0.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.4
     thor (0.14.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/thor-0.14.6
     database_cleaner (bundled(0.7.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.7.1
     diff-lcs (bundled(1.1.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue on Heroku's side that has just arisen in the last day or so. It doesn't appear that they have a fix at this very moment, but they are aware of the issue and working to resolve it.

Here is a link to the github Issue: [Issue #245: Heroku Logs Failing in 2.21.1](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/245)

EDIT: It appears shortly after I posted this, they released a minor revision to 2.21.2 which resolved the issue for me. You can update using a gem update

```
gem update heroku
```